# How can i print the org.eclipse.core.resources for an eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm currently working on an Eclipse plugin.
I want to add an item on right-click menu in WorkbenchView of my plugin.
This item should be visible only to a specific object.

I tried to use the VisibleWhen tag like this :

```
    <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
      <menuContribution
            locationURI="popup:MyURI">
         <command
               commandId="MyCommandId"
               style="push">
            <visibleWhen
                  checkEnabled="false">
               <test
                     property="org.eclipse.core.resources.name"
                     value="WORKSPACE">
               </test>
            </visibleWhen>
         </command>
      </menuContribution>
   </extension>
```

And when I do it the menu item never appears.

So is there a way to test the properties values of org.eclipse.core.resources and know what is wrong with them ?

Thanks.

Alexandre.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
<visibleWhen 
    checkEnabled="false"> 
<iterate>
   <adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource">
      <test property="org.eclipse.core.resources.name" 
            value="*.java"/>
   </adapt>
</iterate>
```

This will show the menu for all of the *.java files. Modify this according to your needs.

Comment: I tried your example, i have a little improuvment. If my WorkbenchView is empty i see my menu item, but when i create an element the item desapear. The objects i create in my WorbenchView are not files, they are specific objects of my plugin. That's why i would like to print values.

Comment: Can you post your improvement as well?